# How to set release profiling in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

I have two configuration, the Debug and Release in  my project. Profiling application in debug mode gives me odd results, because some function do additional checks in DEBUG mode and it is not optimized. Profiling in release mode gives me no information about name of functions, I can see only the time spend in modul.

What is the minimum change for Release configuration to be used with profiler and to be most similar to release in performance? I mean what do I need to change in release configuration to be able to use results from profiler?

Comment: answer's link is broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compile release mode with debug symbols, follow
[these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx)

Comment: answer's link is broken

Comment: yeah, Microsoft move stuff over the years. Google for: _"visual studio c++ compile release with debug symbols"_ gives this [result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2019)